Transfer profile data from old Mac to new without the "garbage"?
I recently transferred the profile I use from my old Mac to a new one.
Thanks to Migration Assistant and Thunderbolt everything went smoothly and fast. That is until I realised all the "garbage" that went along.
When I checked through terminal what the root folder (that is ~/) contained with (ls -la), I saw that all the hidden files went along. That is probably expected. And I don't seem to have the choice to transfer just the data that is contained in the folders/directories of ~/ (that is, the content of Desktop, Documents, etc.), but not the content of ~/Library and other stuff I might not be aware of.
Therefore I decided to erase the profile and do the transfer manually, but I soon had 2 main issues:

I can manage to transfer some data, but not other (i.e., Photos Library.photoslibrary, no matter what I did even following this Apple KB)
Some serious "garbage" was transferred too that I could not locate after the deletion of the profile no matter what I did (see this SE thread for that issue and what I ended up doing).

I guess that the issue resulting from point 1. comes from the fact that although the profile names are the same in one computer and the other, their IDs or fingerprint, or whatever does not match and therefore prohibits the transfer (it can also be because I obviously lack some knowledge).
Therefore, my questions are:

Does Migration Assistant allow, in one way or another, to choose what data is transferred from a User profile?
If this is not possible, is there another way to transfer the data without getting blocked (like what happened with Photos Library.photoslibrary)?


Systems used

"Old" computer: macOS Sonoma 14.6.1, 2.8 GHz, Quad-Core Intel Core i7, 16 GB RAM
"New" computer: macOS Sonoma 14.6.1, Apple M3 Max, 128 GB RAM


P.S.: Transferring the User Profiles with Thunderbolt the nearly 2 TB of data from the "old" computer took 2-3 hours with Migration Assistant. Transferring <100 GB of data from one profile to another by dragging and dropping took also 2-3 hours. The difference is striking!

Caveat: I have no idea what migration-assistant does as I have never used it. However, if you're looking for an approach to copy data from an old Mac to a new Mac, you can take a look at at this "recipe" I created on GitHub. The recipe as written is for performing a backup, but it's easily adaptable to what you're trying to do. Post an Issue if you have questions.

Firstly, Migration Assistant is designed to make your new Mac as close as it can to the old Mac, giving a 'seamless' transition. So, anything that was on your old Mac will get transferred over.
From memory, I'd say that there are some options to select what you bring over, but they are quite broad.
I'd challenge your definition of "garbage". Your user Library contains all your emails, every app's settings, and lots of configuration that you would surely want to keep. Invisible files in your home folder (NB: ~/ is not "root") are probably small in size and likely to be config files that you'll have to recreate anyway.
It's probably easiest to let Migration Assistant "recreate" your old laptop on your new one, and then work out if there's anything you can delete.
